# How to customize numbering style in Word using python docx?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to use python docx to customize a numbering style when adding a paragraph in a Word file.

For example, instead of just adding `'1. '` in the beginning of a paragraph, I wanna do `'class #1. '`.

Is it possible? Is there a function I can use directly?

Comment: It seems possible.

Comment: @WaketZheng is there any functions I can use?

Comment: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx

Comment: @WaketZheng none of them works

Comment: Er, I don't know how to do it now, but I would post a example about changing docx content in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This example pass params to a sample docx:

```py
# generate_roombill_docx.py
import re
from pathlib import Path

from models.earning import RoomBill, c_room_bills_serializer
from models.nezha import get_community_name

from .create_docx_by_sample import docx_replace
from .helper import create_sn, verbose_price


async def gen_docx(roombill: RoomBill, host: str, r2=None, target=None):
    # 创建docx文件，返回文件路径target，指定让r2/c2采取二合一打印

    community_name = await get_community_name(roombill.community)
    room_name = roombill.room_name
    host = host.replace("www.esoaru.net", "esoaru.net")
    img = qrcode_path(host, community_name, roombill.room_slug)
    where = Path(__file__).parent
    sample = where / "sample_模板2.docx"
    bills, total = await c_room_bills_serializer([roombill])
    params = build_params(
        bills,
        room_name,
        community_name,
        total,
        roombill.name,
        roombill.remark,
        roombill.period,
    )
    img_data = {"img_paycode": img}
    if community_name == "xxx":
        params["who"] = (
            "深圳艺坤家园物业管理有限公司"
            "\n"
            "服务中心电话: 0755-28281233 (8:30-21:00)"
            "\n"
            "监控中心电话: 0755-28283118 (7*24小时)"
        )
    else:
        params["who"] = ""
    if r2:
        # TODO 2.2: 两个单打印在同一张纸
        where = Path(__file__).parent
        sample = where / "double_sample.docx"
    if target is None:
        media = Path("media")
        name = f"{room_name}_{r2}.docx" if r2 else f"{room_name}.docx"
        target = media / community_name / "通知单" / name
        target.parent.exists() or target.parent.mkdir(parents=True)
    docx_replace(sample, target, params, img_data)
    return str(target)


def doc_fmt(detail):
    if not detail:
        return ""
    d = re.sub(r"<[a-z /]+>", "", detail)
    d = re.sub(r"&nbsp;?", " ", d)
    d = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", d)
    return d


def build_params(
    bills: dict,
    unit: str,
    community_name: str,
    total: str,
    bill_name: str,
    remark: str = "",
    period: str = "",  # 计费周期备注
) -> dict:
    """构造出模板需要的参数"""
    sn = create_sn()
    d = {"room": unit, "community": community_name, "sn": sn}
    d["total"] = str(total)
    d["verbose"] = total and verbose_price(total) or ""
    d["bill_name"] = bill_name
    d["period_tip"] = "计费周期备注:" if period else ""
    d["period"] = period or ""
    d["tip"] = "备注:" if remark else ""
    d["remark"] = remark or ""
    line_num = 1
    for bill_id, bill_data in bills.items():
        for charge_item in bill_data["charges"]:
            for i in charge_item["items"]:
                a, b, c = f"n{line_num}1", f"n{line_num}2", f"n{line_num}3"
                d[a], d[b], d[c] = i["title"], i["amount"], i["detail"]
                line_num += 1
    for i in range(1, 10):
        for j in range(1, 4):
            k = f"n{i}{j}"
            d.setdefault(k, "")
    return d


def qrcode_path(host: str, community_name: str, room_slug: str) -> str:
    """返回二维码图片地址，如果图片不存在就调用qrcode生成它"""
    media = "media"
    p = Path(media) / "qrcodes" / community_name / f"{room_slug}.jpg"
    if not p.exists():
        if not p.parent.exists():
            p.parent.mkdir(parents=True)
        import qrcode

        if "wanghai" not in host:
            qr_host = "https://www.esoaru.com"
        else:
            qr_host = host.replace("wanghai", "www")
        link = f"{qr_host}/dist/bill/{room_slug}/paper"
        qrcode.make(link).save(p)
    return str(p)
```

create_docx_by_sample.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Optional, Union

from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Cm


def docx_replace(
    sample_path: Union[str, Path],
    savepath: Union[str, Path],
    params: dict,
    images: Optional[dict] = None,
) -> None:
    """根据给定模板和参数, 构造新的Word文档, 并保存在本地"""

    document = Document(sample_path)
    if images is None:
        images = {}

    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:

        for run in paragraph.runs:
            rtext = run.text
            for k, v in params.items():
                vname = "${%s}" % k
                if vname in rtext:
                    run.text = rtext.replace(vname, v)

            for k, v in images.items():
                vname = "${%s}" % k

                if vname in rtext:
                    run.clear()
                    run.add_picture(v, height=Cm(4.75))

    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        ptext = paragraph.text
        # print(ptext)
        for k, v in params.items():
            vname = "${%s}" % k
            if vname in ptext:
                paragraph.text = ptext.replace(vname, v)

    for table in document.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    ptext = paragraph.text
                    for k, v in params.items():
                        vname = "${%s}" % k
                        if vname in ptext:
                            paragraph.text = ptext.replace(vname, v)

                    for k, v in images.items():
                        vname = "${%s}" % k

                        if vname in ptext:
                            # print(ptext)
                            paragraph.clear()
                            run = paragraph.add_run()
                            run.add_picture(v, height=Cm(4.0))
    document.save(savepath)


def main() -> None:
    params = {
        "room": "10-005",
        "sn": "5213",
        "n11": "历史账单:",
        "n12": "物业费",
        "n13": "100.00",
        "n21": "",
        "n22": "停车费",
        "n23": "200",
        "n31": "7月账单:",
        "n32": "物业费",
        "n33": "100.00",
        "n41": "",
        "n42": "停车费",
        "n43": "200",
        "n51": "8月账单:",
        "n52": "物业费",
        "n53": "100.00",
        "n61": "",
        "n62": "停车费",
        "n63": "200",
        "n71": "",
        "n72": "总计:",
        "n73": "5320.00",
    }
    where = Path(__file__).parent
    docx_replace(
        where / "sample.docx",
        where / "cuishoudan_demo.docx",
        params,
        {"img_paycode": str(where / "gyy.jpg")},
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if 'test' in sys.argv:
        main()
```

sample.docx: https://waketzheng.top/public/docx/sample.docx